# How to add external js script in block via requireJs?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

What is the simplest way to add external js script like:
`https://sandbox-geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js`
on my page? I've created block which i render on my product page. But i get an error.
`Error: Script error for:` and also `mismatch error`.
I've tried:
**requirejs-config.js:**

```
var config = {
    map: {
       '*': {
           'map' : 'https://sandbox-geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js'
       }
    }
};
```

also tried:

```
var config = {
     paths: {
        map: 'https://sandbox-geowidget.easypack24.net/js/sdk-for-javascript.js'
    }
};
```

then in my js file:

```
require(['map'], function () {
        window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {
            easyPack.init({});
            var map = easyPack.mapWidget('map', function(point){
            });
        }
});
```

but i get above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

> requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            sdkjavascript: 'Vendorname_ModuleName/js/sdkjavascript'
        }
    }
};
```

save external js in below folder like

> Vendorname/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/sdkjavascript.js

Then try in custom js

```
require([
  'sdkjavascript'], function () {
        window.easyPackAsyncInit = function () {
            easyPack.init({});
            var map = easyPack.mapWidget('sdkjavascript', function(point){
            });
        }
});
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still get mismatched error. Sometimes it works. Sometimes it does not work...

Comment: I checked requirejs-config.js in my pub/static/.... and there is this file. It is also included in head tag...